# Custom USQL extractor - How to process more than 4 MB json object

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

We use a custom USQL extractor to flatten a json structure. The below sample code works fine if line(json object) of json is less than 4 MB. If the line size is above 4 MB, then we get error **"A record in the input file is longer than 4194304 bytes."** The similar code is tried in C# stand alone application for lines higher than 4 MB, it works fine. Do we have any restriction on json size with usql custom extractor? How do we handle json messages with size more than 4 MB?
The error is thrown from the highlighted line in below code 
**string line = lineReader.ReadToEnd();**

**Custom extractor Sample code**

using Microsoft.Analytics.Interfaces;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Analytics.Types.Sql;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Company.DataLakeAnalytics
 
{
    [SqlUserDefinedExtractor(AtomicFileProcessing = false)]
    public class CustomJSONExtractor : IExtractor
    {
        private readonly Encoding _encoding;
        private readonly byte[] _row_delim;
        private string DELIMITER = "~";
        public CustomJSONExtractor(Encoding encoding = null, string row_delim = "\r\n")
        {
            _encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            _row_delim = _encoding.GetBytes(row_delim);
        }
        //Every json line in the raw file is transformed to a flat structure
        public override IEnumerable Extract(IUnstructuredReader input, IUpdatableRow output)
        {
            //Read the input line by line
            foreach (Stream current in input.Split(_row_delim))
            {
                using (StreamReader lineReader = new StreamReader(current, this._encoding))
                {
                    //reads the entire line
                    **string line = lineReader.ReadToEnd();**

                    //break the line to multiple variables
                    output.Set(1, "A~1");
                    yield return output.AsReadOnly();
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}

### sample USQL code

DECLARE @INPUT_FILE="sample-data.txt";
@jsonDatafile = EXTRACT  key string, jsonObjStr string FROM @INPUT_FILE USING new Damen.DataLakeAnalytics.CustomJSONExtractor(null,row_delim:"\n") ;
@dataJsonObject = SELECT jsonObjStr AS rawData FROM @dataAsStrings;
OUTPUT @dataJsonObject TO @flattenedOutputFile USING Outputters.Text(outputHeader:false,quoting: false,delimiter:'~');

Comment: I was able to process a much bigger file on (local-machine) ADLS. Please, be more specific, or send a snippet which u say is working on standalone C# app.

Comment: @Milan-below code works, as I mentioned lineReader.ReadToEnd() was failing in ADLA but it works in below program, have you tried in azure cloud?                                          public class Utility
    {
        public static string ProcessData()
        {
            using (StreamReader lineReader = new StreamReader("{pathToaFile}test-data-1.txt"))
   {
    string line = lineReader.ReadToEnd();
    int a = line.Length;
    Console.WriteLine("char length:" + a);
   }
        }
 }

Answer (score 0):

The max size is indeed 4MB for rows and 128KB for a string. What you can do is using the solution provided in this similar answer:

[What is the maximum allowed size for String in U-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36937965/what-is-the-maximum-allowed-size-for-string-in-u-sql)